# Why does my main content overlaps my sticky top bar in Blazor Syncfusion?

Tags: html, css, header, blazor, syncfusion

I'm creating a application in Syncfusion blazor and this total content is divided in two sections: top row and content. The top row is sticky but somehow when I scroll down the main content will overlap the top row, I want that top row is always visible and wont get overlapped, how can i achieve this?

Default scroll position(on top):

[image]

When scrolled down a tiny bit:

[image]

As u can see the main content will overlap the top row, how can i avoid this and get the main content behind this top row bar instead of over the bar?

CSS top row:

[image]

CSS main content:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a z-index: 2000 to .top-row in site.css.

This will make the header the top most layer so the content won't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the css style position as initial for chart. Please check with the below code snippet and sample.

**Code Snippet**

```
<style>   
.e-chart {
    position: initial !important;
}
</style>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Sample**
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartPosition-340277043.zip

Thanks,
Durga G